# {JAVA} Implementing equals(Object o) method for my lookUp method

Tags: java, object, equals, indexof

I need to implement equals method according to the following method.

```
 public class Database{

 .........

//A helper method to look for a patron using 
//id. If found, it returns it, otherwise, it returns null.

public Patron lookUp(int id) {
    int val = patrons.indexOf(id);
    if(val!=-1){return patrons.get(val);}
    else
        return null;}}
```

The equals method is in patron class, and I wrote the following code for it.

```
public class Patron{

.........

//Need to implement this in order to have a 
//method such as indexOf of ArrayList work properly

public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if(!(o instanceof Patron)){
       return false;}
   else{
        return true;}}
```

So basically I need to check if there exists a patron with the provided id number using the indexOf method. For this, we created the equals method in the Patron class. But it doesn't work and always returns -1.

Below are the both classes.

```
 import java.util.*;
 public class Database{
// Declare an ArrayList of patrons
ArrayList<Patron> patrons;

// Constructor 
public Database()
{
    patrons = new ArrayList<Patron>();
}

// [5 points] A method that adds a patron object. It 
//returns false if the patron already exists, 
//otherwise it returns true. You should use the 
//lookUp method below.
public boolean add( Patron p  ){
    if(lookUp(p.id)==null){
        patrons.add(p);     
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

// [5 points] A helper method to look for a patron using 
//id. If found, it returns it, otherwise, it returns null.
public Patron lookUp(int id) {
    int val = patrons.indexOf(id);
    if(val!=-1){
        return patrons.get(val);
    }
    else
        return null;}}
```

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class Patron{

//Data members: id, name, a list of checked out books
int id;
String name;
ArrayList<Book> booksCheckedOut;

// [3 points] Constructor
public Patron(int id, String name)
{ this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  booksCheckedOut = new ArrayList<Book>();
}

//A method to return the id
public int getID() {
    return id;
}

// [5 points] Need to implement this in order to have a 
//method such as indexOf of ArrayList work properly
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if(!(o instanceof Patron)){
       return false;
    }
   else{
        return true;
}
}       

// [2 points] A method to check out a book by adding it 
//to the ArrayList above
public void addBook(String bookTitle, double bookPrice){
    Book b = new Book(bookTitle,bookPrice);
    booksCheckedOut.add(b);
}

// [5 points] List all books in the ArrayList
public void showStatement() {
    for(Book val: booksCheckedOut){
        System.out.println(val);}}}
```

Comment: You want to use Map<Integer,Patron> instead. Also, horrible horrible `equals` method there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `indexOf` of an `ArrayList<Patron>` to return anything other than -1, you must pass to it an instance of `Patron`.

Passing an `int`, as you do here

```
int val = patrons.indexOf(id);
```

will always return -1.

If you want to be able to lookup `Patron`s by their identifiers, use a `HashMap<Integer,Patron>` instead of a `List`.

Or you can change your `Patron lookUp(int id)` to `Patron lookUp(Patron p)` and pass to it `p` instead of `p.id` in your `add` method.

P.S., I'm assuming your implementation of `equals` in `Patron` class is incomplete, since it always returns `true` when you pass a `Patron` instance to it.

Comment: actually I am not supposed to change the method parameters, as they are given to me (I am a student). So I can only write the code for the given method.

Comment: @AbdulBasitKhan Which method of all the methods you posted is the method you are supposed to change?